# Changing plot to log scale but keeping axes in not log scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I have code that looks like this currently (from the help of many of you on this website, so thank you!)

```
#my data
DF <- data.table("Site_No" = c(123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123), 
 "variable" = 
c(1,1,2,2,5,5,10,10,20,20,25,25,30,30,40,40,50,50,60,60,70,70,75,75,80,80,90,90,95,95,98,98,99,99), 
"Test" = c("value.x", "value.y", "value.x", "value.y", "value.x", "value.y","value.x", "value.y", 
"value.x", "value.y", "value.x", "value.y","value.x", "value.y", "value.x", "value.y", "value.x", 
"value.y","value.x", "value.y", "value.x", "value.y", "value.x", "value.y","value.x", "value.y", 
"value.x", "value.y","value.x", "value.y","value.x", "value.y","value.x", "value.y"),                                                                                                                                               
"Value" = c(800, 700, 600, 580, 570, 560, 520, 500, 430, 415, 412, 402, 380, 370, 366, 300, 290, 280, 
270, 260,  250, 240, 230, 220, 210, 200, 180, 160, 150, 130, 100, 95, 67, 40))


#create plots
for (i in unique(DF$Site_No)){
graph <- ggplot(data = DF[Site_No == i,], mapping = aes(x = variable, y = Value, group 
                                                      = Test)) +
geom_line(aes(color = Test)) +
scale_color_discrete(labels = c("annual","winter"))+
scale_x_discrete(name ="Percent Chance Flow Exceeded", 
                     limits=c("1", "10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90", "99"))+
labs(x = "Percent Chance Flow Exceeded", y = "Streamflow, In cubic feet per second")+
ggtitle(paste(i))

ggsave(filename = paste0("Site_",i,".png"), plot = graph, device = "png", width  = 5, height = 5, units = "in")
}
```

Here are my requests that I would like to be changed please!
1) Make the x-axis be spaced like this:
0.5, 2, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 70, 80, 90, 95, 98, 99

2) Make both of the lines (annual and winter) be in log scale, but keep the y-axis NOT in log scale!

Thank you so much for your help :)!!!

Comment: what do you mean, make the lines in log scale, but keep the axis not in log??

Comment: I would like "Value" to be logged, but keep the y-axis not in log scale!

Comment: What about passing `y = log(Value)` in your `aes` ? Does it solve your question ?

Answer (score 1):

I am using data.frame, so I can use regular tidyverse piping. 
You need to transform your data before plotting. I'd do this before passing your data to the for loop. I removed this loop in this example, because your data only contained one ID.

In order to show axis breaks at round 'readable' numbers, you need the log values of those round numbers for the axis breaks, and then for the labels use the exponent to the log... if this makes sense. See code.

```r
library(tidyverse)
DF <- data.frame("Site_No" = c(123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123), 
                 "variable" = 
                   c(1,1,2,2,5,5,10,10,20,20,25,25,30,30,40,40,50,50,60,60,70,70,75,75,80,80,90,90,95,95,98,98,99,99), 
                 "Test" = c("value.x", "value.y", "value.x", "value.y", "value.x", "value.y","value.x", "value.y", 
                            "value.x", "value.y", "value.x", "value.y","value.x", "value.y", "value.x", "value.y", "value.x", 
                            "value.y","value.x", "value.y", "value.x", "value.y", "value.x", "value.y","value.x", "value.y", 
                            "value.x", "value.y","value.x", "value.y","value.x", "value.y","value.x", "value.y"),                                                                                                                                               
                 "Value" = c(800, 700, 600, 580, 570, 560, 520, 500, 430, 415, 412, 402, 380, 370, 366, 300, 290, 280, 
                             270, 260,  250, 240, 230, 220, 210, 200, 180, 160, 150, 130, 100, 95, 67, 40))


DF %>% mutate(logval = log(Value)) %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = variable, y = logval, group  = Test)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Test)) +
  scale_color_discrete(labels = c("annual","winter")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = log(seq(100,800,100)), labels = exp(log(seq(100,800,100)))) +
  scale_x_discrete(name ="Percent Chance Flow Exceeded", 
                   limits=c( 0.5, 2, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 70, 80, 90, 95, 98, 99)) +
  labs(x = "Percent Chance Flow Exceeded", y = "Streamflow, In cubic feet per second")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! However, is there a way to keep the y-axis not in log scale (so the scale would be 0 to 800) but still have the line be the way it is now?

Comment: But I'm running this in a batch of 100 different Site_No's so the min won't always be 100 and the max won't always be 800. Is there a way for it to look and see what an appropriate scale is for each site in the for loop?

Comment: Thank you for all of the help so far though, if you could help with that last piece, I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: @Sarah Almost worth a new question, but I guess there are similar problems out there. I guess the easiest option is first to find miminum and maximum value for each Site, and generate reasonable breaks/labels for each, and store this in a list with the same indices as the list which you use for the plot. U can then use those list entries for your for loop. Hope this makes sense.